# Harp and browser-sync invoked by package.json with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browser-sync, harp

I'd like to facilitate a way to start a harp.js server and run a browser-sync process at the same time. It's working like a charm on Linux. This is the content of my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "bash ./serve.sh"
  }
}
```

And this is the serve.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
harp server &
browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:9000' --files '*.jade, *.less'
```

When doing this on windows, I am supposed to do a bat file I presume, but isn't there a way to translate harp server & browser-sync etc etc to a corresponding command on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a `package.json` file, we would do something like this instead.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "harp server & browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:9000' --files '*.jade, *.less'"
  }
}
```

give that a spin.